# Ruby How to convert back binary string from smsc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8

my app work with SMSC, and i need to get involve in sms before it send,

i try to send from the mobile that string

> "hello this is test"

And when I check the smsc I got this as binary string of my text:

```
userData = "c8329bfd06d1d1e939283d07d1cb733a"
```

the encoding of this string is:

```
<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

I know that probably this userData is in GSM encoding in binary-string

so how can i get from userData back the clear text string ?

this question is for english lang, because in Hebrew I can get back the 
string with this code:

`[userData].pack('H*').force_encoding('utf-16be').encode('utf-8')`

but in english i got error:

```
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: "\xDA\xF3" followed by "u" on UTF-16BE
```

What I was try is to detect the binary string with ICU, and I got:

"ISO-8859-1" and the language that detected is: 'PT', that very strange cause my languages is English or Hebrew.

anyway i got lost with encoding stuff, so i try to encode to each name of list from `Encoding.list`

but without luck until now

thanks in advance

Shmulik

Answer (score 0):

OK,

For who that also have this issue, i got the solution, thanks to someone from #ruby irc community (i missed his nickname)

The solution is:

for **ascii** chars that interpolate to binary:

You need that:

```
"c8329bfd06d1d1e939283d07d1cb733a".scan(/../).reverse_each.map { |h| h.to_i(16) }.pack('C*').unpack('B*')[0][2..-1].scan(/.{7}/).map.with_object("") { |x, s| s << x.to_i(2) }.reverse
```

Remember I sent this words in sms:

> "hello this is test"

And that it has become in binary to:

> "c8329bfd06d1d1e939283d07d1cb733a"

The reason that i got garbage in any encoding is, because the ascii chars is 7bits GSM, so only first 7bits represents the data but each another encoding uses at least 8bits, so that what the code actually do.

*But this is just for **ascii** char set.*

In another language like I use Hebrew, the SMS send as **ucs2**

So this code work for me:

```
[your_binary_string].pack('H*').force_encoding('utf-16be').encode('utf-8')
```

**Very important to put the binary string in array**

So that all for now.

If anybody want to translate and explain what exactly happen in the code for ascii char set, be my guest and welcome.

Shmulik